# postgresql to_json() function escapes all doublequote characters

Tags: sql, json, postgresql-9.3

I've written a plpgsql script which generates an array of json objects in a string but after I use to_json() method passing a variable with that string to it, it returns a result which is doublequoted and also every doublequote character is escaped. But I need that string as is.

initial content of jsonResult variable is:

> [{"key":{04949429911,"Code":"400"},"value":"20000.00"},{"key":{"InsuranceNumber":"04949429911","Code":"403"},"value":"10000.00"},...]

but after to_json() it looks like this:

> "[{\"key\":{04949429911,\"Code\":\"400\"},\"value\":\"20000.00\"},{\"key\":{\"InsuranceNumber\":\"04949429911\",\"Code\":\"403\"},\"value\":\"10000.00\"}...]"

This is the place where everything stored in jsonResult breakes:

```
UPDATE factor_value SET params = to_json(jsonResult) WHERE id = _id;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't get it. You already *have* json in your initial variable. Why call `to_json()` on it?

Comment: My initial jsonResult variable is of type varchar and is built by several concatenations and I need to insert it into a column with type JSON. Sorry, haven't mentioned it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26156547/785663) points out that simply casting to `json` should suffice:

```
UPDATE factor_value SET params = jsonResult::json WHERE id = _id;
```

The weird escaping you see is probably due to postgresql not realizing you already have valid JSON and your `varchar` is just converted to a plain javascript/JSON string.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried to do so. Nothing happens... I used `raise  notice` to check the contents and it raises nothing...

Comment: This is the full contents of `jsonResult` variable I'm trying to save: `NOTICE:  qwe,[{"key":{04949429911,"Code":"400"},"value":"20000.00"},{"key":{"InsuranceNumber":"04949429911","Code":"403"},"value":"10000.00"},{"key":{"InsuranceNumber":"05548560177","Code":"400"},"value":"20000.00"},{"key":{"InsuranceNumber":"05548560177","Code":"403"},"value":"10000.00"}]`

Comment: Now that you said it.. If you add the missing key, does it insert okay?

Comment: Terribly sorry for wasting your time... Fixed generation of json string and it updated everything as it should using `jsonResult::json`.

Comment: No worries, I haven't noticed the missing key, either.

Comment: Best answer so far, tried so many things but simply appending ::json worked!

Answer (score 2):

I needed to convert a bytea column to jsonb and I ended up with escaped characters when using to_json.  I also used bytea_data_column::jsonb and postgres said cannot cast to jsonb.  Here is how I worked around it:

`bytea_data_column::text::jsonb`